# cartesian coordinate generator, XYZ point data generator,

Tags: windows, geo-location, geography

[image]

I want to be able to draw some terrain like in the picture attached(minus the aircraft) and have the XYZ Cartesian coordinates of the points of the terrain returned to me. I need the data for experimental purposes and DEM files from NASA are not in XYZ format. Is there any software to help me do this?

Comment: What format are DEM files in?

Comment: Do you want real data?  Or just data based on whatever you draw and your own definition of x,y,z...

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a Geographic Information System (GIS) such as [QGIS](http://qgis.org/), *(Quantum GIS),* possibly with the [GRASS](http://grass.osgeo.org/) plug-ins.

QGIS is:

- A cross-platform free and open-source desktop geographic information system
- GNU GPL licenced
- Can import data in a number of formats.

GRASS is:

- Geographic Resources Analysis Support System
- Free and open-source software
- Cross Platform
- under the GNU General Public License
- Adds a large number of import formats
- Also has command line/shell interfaces

GRASS GIS contains over 350 modules to render maps and images on monitor and paper; manipulate raster and vector data including vector networks; process multispectral image data; and create, manage, and store spatial data

You will have some learning to do but there are active and helpful online communities available.